# Save As to specific location using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have working code that copies cells in a file and pastes into a newly created document that is generated with VBA code.  I am looking to Save As this newly created document, which is currently is able to do.  I created a csPath variable to try and specify a location for the document to Save As in, but it will only either save on my desktop or runs into an error.  Any advice?

```
'Declaring variables for the Save As function  
Dim fname As Variant            ' Required for declaring the document name
Dim NewWb As Workbook           ' Specifies the new workbook for the Save As function
Dim FileFormatValue As Long     ' Allows programmer to declare what file formats that can be in the Save As function, currently only .xlsx
Dim csPath As String            ' Allows program to set location for Save As function

'Begin the Save As function for easy operator reference of old batches

csPath = "\\346nafp1\shares$\Departments\Starch\Wetend\Transfer\old - dont touch\"

' Check the Excel version
If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then Exit Sub
If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then

    ' Only choice in the "Save as type" dropdown is Excel files(xls)
    ' if the Excel version is 2000-2003
    fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", _
    Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", _
    Title:="This example copies the ActiveSheet to a new workbook")

    If fname <> False Then
        ' Copy the ActiveSheet to new workbook
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook

        ' We use the 2000-2003 format xlWorkbookNormal here to save as xls
        NewWb.SaveAs fname, FileFormat:=-4143, CreateBackup:=False
        NewWb.Close False
        Set NewWb = Nothing

    End If
Else
    ' Force to save as .xls for archiving in the History folder
    ' Files available there for use in the future for reference
    ' But disable macros to prevent changing or confusion when looking at archives

    fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Worksheets("Oxy1").Cells(4, 7) & " " & Worksheets("Oxy1").Cells(4, 11), _
        Filefilter:= _
        " Excel Macro Free Workbook (*.xls), *.xls,", _
        FilterIndex:=2, Title:="Save and archive for new batch")

        ' Add the code to the Filefilter above if additional formats are needed
        ' Include " before the word Excel to add it in
        ' Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
        ' Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & _
        ' Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", _

    ' Find the correct FileFormat that match the choice in the "Save as type" list
    If fname <> False Then
        Select Case LCase(Right(fname, Len(fname) - InStrRev(fname, ".", , 1)))
        Case "xls": FileFormatValue = 56
        Case "xlsx": FileFormatValue = 51
        Case "xlsm": FileFormatValue = 52
        Case "xlsb": FileFormatValue = 50
        Case Else: FileFormatValue = 0
        End Select

        ' Now we can create/Save the file with the xlFileFormat parameter
        ' value that match the file extension
        If FileFormatValue = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Sorry, unknown file extension"
        Else
            ' Copies the ActiveSheet to new workbook
            ActiveSheet.Copy
            Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Save the file in the format you choose in the "Save as type" dropdown
            NewWb.SaveAs fname, FileFormat:= _
                         FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False
            NewWb.Close False
            Set NewWb = Nothing

        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it in your saveas with the filename:= argument.

**NOTE:** Not sure if it is going to like saving to a UNC\share.

```
NewWb.SaveAs filename:="C:\Temp\NewFilename.xls", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False
```

or with your variable

```
NewWb.SaveAs filename:=csPath & "\NewFilename.xls", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False
```

Also here in some infor on the fileformat arg. Not sure what your `FileFormat:=-4143` is trying to do.

These are the main file formats in Excel 2007-2016, Note: In Excel for the Mac the values are +1

> 51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
>   52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
>   50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or
>    without macro's, xlsb)
>   56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel
>   2007-2013, xls)

Comment: Do I have to include the \NewFilename.xls in the line of code?  The code decides what to name the document based on the value of two cells.

Comment: It does have to have a valid path\filename.   \NewFilename.xls is just an example.

Comment: @C.Jacobs - You are attempting to save this as TXT (e.g. (-4143 = xlCurrentPlatformText in [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)). Do NOT put .xls on the tail end if you are changing the file type. Do NOT put anything on the end... ever. Let the file type assign the correct file extension.